# Spring Social Facebook Login Issue

Tags: spring, spring-social-facebook

When I am trying to sign in through Facebook, using spring social I am getting following error:

> WARN org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for
>   "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" resulted in 400 (Bad
>   Request); invoking error handler

Please suggest

```
Configurations

Version of Spring
<org.springframework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<org.springframework.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
<org.spring.social>1.1.0.RELEASE</org.spring.social>


<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg index="3"
            ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
        <!-- Sets the url of the registration form. -->
        <property name="signupUrl" value="/user/register" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configures the social authentication provider which processes authentication 
        requests made by using supported social authentication services (FB, Twitter 
        and so on). -->
    <bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="socialUserDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <!-- service registry will holds connection factory of each social provider -->
    <bean id="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"
        class="org.ecomm.social.model.AppSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="facebookAuthenticationService" />
                <ref bean="googleAuthenticationService" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="facebookAuthenticationService"
        class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
        <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="<apiKey>" />
        <constructor-arg name="appSecret"
            value="<appSecret>" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="googleAuthenticationService"
        class="org.springframework.social.google.security.GoogleAuthenticationService">
        <constructor-arg name="apiKey"
            value="<apiKey>" />
        <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="<appSecret>" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="socialUserDetailsService" class="org.ecomm.service.impl.SocialUserDetailsServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository" class="org.ecomm.social.mongo.MongoUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionService" />
        <constructor-arg ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
        <property name="connectionSignUp" ref="connectionSignUp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionService" class="org.ecomm.social.mongo.MongoConnectionService">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="connectionConverter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionConverter" class="org.ecomm.social.mongo.ConnectionConverter">
        <constructor-arg index="0"
            ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="textEncryptor" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="userIdSource"
        class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

    <bean id="connectionSignUp" class="org.ecomm.social.model.AppConnectionSignUp" />


    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />


    <bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
        <constructor-arg ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="signInAdapter" class="org.ecomm.service.impl.SpringSecuritySignInAdapter"></bean>

    <bean id="providerSignInController"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
        <constructor-arg ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg ref="signInAdapter" />
    </bean>
```

Google Plus code is working fine with this configuration.
But when I am running with spring social facebook I am facing the issue 
WARN org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" resulted in 400 (Bad
Request); invoking error handler

I tried finding solution , but not able to find any solution for same.
Please suggest which part of configuration is missing.

Comment: I suggest posting some of your code.

Comment: I think your post body has issues.

Comment: @GergelyBacso added the configuration code, please suggest